# awk - insert a row when value in column changes

Tags: awk, insert, compare

Using awk I would like to insert a row whenever the value in the second column changes.

I have:

```
1 3
2 3
3 1
4 1
5 2
```

I would like to get:

```
1 3
2 3
>
3 1
4 1
>
5 2
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction how this can be achieved in one file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==1{prev=$2; print; next} prev!=$2{print ">"} {prev=$2}1' file
```